# Create user in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases

Would like to know how to run the command and create the new user in the platform? I read the guide and try to run in console/shell, but not work.

[Guide](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/security/authentication-authorization/native-user-role-management/procedures/#userauth-list-all-users)

(i.e. CALL dbms.security.createUser('test', 'test', false))

> Error message: There is no procedure with the name
>   `dbms.security.createUser` registered for this database instance.
>   Please ensure you've spelled the procedure name correctly and that the
>   procedure is properly deployed.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm running into the same issue using neo4j:latest docker-container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely you're not using Neo4j version 3.1 or greater. Security features and user administration procedures were only introduced with version 3.1.

Versions 3.0 and below use a single user model.

Answer (score -4):

oh why making simple thing complicated just look at syntax/command forget about
which db/language ,why one opening and 2 closing brackets,remove one of closing bracket command will run fine

Comment: Hi lucky, welcome to SO. Please try to give a well written and formatted answer: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer